# Not able to Pass class object reference through <apex:param>?

Tags: visualforce

I have a dataTable which is iterating  over lineItems which is a object of a class InvLineItem ,i need to call a action function which will take InvLineItem object as argument but its working.
tested with some other data types like Sting or number,Its working with them,
Please tell me if there is any way to do this??

**Page**

```
<apex:dataTable id="LineItem" value="{!lineItems}" var="lineItemSUT">  
<script>  
onChangeProduct(lineItemSUT);  
</script>   
</apex:dataTable>  
<apex:actionFunction name="onChangeProduct"  action="{!updateProductItem}" oncomplete="CODA.resumeQueueProcessing(); >   
    <apex:param name="lineItemSUTParam" assignTo="{!lineItem}" value="" />  
</apex:actionFunction>
```

**Controller**

```
 InvLineItem lineItem{get;set;}

 public InvLineItem[] getLineItems()
 {
         lineItem.callOtherFunc();
 }

  public void updateProductItem()
  {

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [apex:param documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_param.htm) confirms that:

> The value attribute must be set to a string, number, or boolean value.

A common approach is to pass an object ID (yeah the documentation doesn't mention that) and then in your Apex logic query for or otherwise find the matching object.

For your case where you are using an inner class, you will need to add some sort of ID that you populate to your LineItem inner class (could be as simple as an index number 0, 1, 2 3 etc) and then you can use code like this to find the matching item:

```
// apex:param sets this value
String lineItemId {get; set;}

// Keep hold of all the line items
InvLineItem[] lineItems {get; set;}

// Returns the selected item
InvLineItem lineItem {
     get {
         for (LineItem li : lineItems) {
             if (li.id == lineItemId) {
                 return li;
             }
         }
         return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes..But i am not setting value attribute, I am setting assignTo and this is not a custom object reference it is reference of some inner class

Comment: @VikasKhandelwal See addition to answer.

Comment: Actually previously this apex:actionFunction was in <apex:dataTable> but from API version 23 we can't use action function inside irritable component, I had to take it out from dataTable.  [Note: Beginning with API version 23 you can't place <apex:actionFunction> inside an iteration component — <apex:pageBlockTable>  <apex:repeat>, and so on. Put the <apex:actionFunction> after the iteration component, and inside the iteration put a normal JavaScript function that calls it.](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm)

Comment: @VikasKhandelwal If you have a working solution using API 22 or earlier and don't need any features from the later API versions, I would leave the working code alone. See [Automating revision of version settings for apex classes](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51513/automating-revision-of-version-settings-for-apex-classes/51521#51521) to support that approach.

Comment: I have a task to update all api version, so i have no other option :P

Comment: @VikasKhandelwal I side with the view in the link in my previous comment that there is little advantage in always trying to move to the latest version and considerable risk. One of our managed packages uses API versions from 18 up to the current API version.