# Which API versions are still supported?

Tags: api-version

I see some [posts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/76171/36989) that Salesforce supports all the back versions of its APIs.

But I also see [pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_support_policy.htm) on [Salesforce.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm) that only give an End of Life statement that API versions will be supported for 3 years after their release date.

Which is it? Which versions are still supported today?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that an API level being unsupported just means that Salesforce won't release patches to fix issues for that version, not that you can't use it.

If you go to your organization and try to edit the version of the Salesforce.com API used on a class, it will show options that range from API 10 to API 40 at the moment.

[image]

Same thing goes for Visualforce. But the levels are a little different. Visualforce is supported on APIs 15 to 40.

Comment: I suspect if you raise a support case from a really old API version SF will probably advise upgrading to a more recent version as the best way to fix it.

Answer (score 9):

Salesforce has the **option** of deprecating/removing an API after three years (the *minimum* amount of time the API is supported). Before they do this, they will post an announcement and contact customers that they detect are still using an older API version. There are different cutoff values for different features. Features that did not exist in a particular release may not work in older API versions (and generally do not). For example, the only valid values for the REST API are versions 20.0 and greater.

Generally speaking, when developing new code, you should choose the latest API version, or preferably [the same API version as the rest of your code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70387/what-is-the-best-practice-re-api-version-of-your-apex-classes) (whichever makes more sense). Using the oldest possible version increases the odds that you'll need to do maintenance sooner rather than later. Until/unless you get a notification about a deprecated API, feel free to use whatever version makes the most sense for your scenario, and remember to read the release notes for each version as they come out so you won't be blindsided by deprecated APIs when/if they happen.

Answer (score 7):

Anecdotally, I've been working with the SOAP API for more than 10 years now. In that time I've only ever [seen one notification](https://twitter.com/FishOfPrey/status/868915614730960896) of older API versions being deprecated -
Knowledge Article: [SOAP API Legacy Versions Retirement](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000250959&type=1&language=en_US). That was for API versions upto v6.0. And note this isn't even going to happen until Summer '18.

However, as a rule of thumb, try and keep everything one a consistent API version within the last 3 years so you don't get a big shock if they one day decide to force things onto the newer API versions.

You might find that this recent API retirement is a test bed for Salesforce. I.e. Getting themselves setup with processes to retire older API versions. Identify affected customers, etc...

Of course, that is only conjecture on my part.

---

Update: **Summer '21** with see API versions for the SOAP/REST/BULK APIs ending support for v20 and earlier. [Lightning Platform API legacy versions retirement](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000351312&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

---

Update: **Summer '22** will see a further set of API versions being retired - up to and including v30.0. [Salesforce Platform API Versions 21.0 thru 30.0](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000354473&type=1&mode=1&language=en_US)

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce Support and the help page "Salesforce Platform API Versions 21.0 through 30.0 Retirement" at https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389618&type=1 tell me that it is not necessary to change the API level of your custom Apex classes if they are at a deprecated or unsupported API level!

But, Salesforce Support may not help with problems caused by using unsupported levels.

Answer (score 0):

You can diagnose your production org using `sfdx hardis:org:diagnose:legacyapi`

All is explained here :)

https://nicolasvuillamy.medium.com/handle-salesforce-api-versions-deprecation-like-a-pro-335065f52238